# compare textfield.text to firebase string swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a database in Firebase that will have individual user nodes. In each user's node will be data pertaining to them and will be private. In addition to that I want to create a node that is JUST a collection of registered emails. The reason is when a user is on the Sign In VC and the user types an email in..If the email is already registered an image view will turn green. However, if the email is not in the database (or if it doesn't match email address format) the image will be red.

A previous answer on my previous question(s) illustrated that I need to change the '.' to a ',' in email addresses. So @gmail.com would be stored as gmail,com

I have that down.

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

    if error == nil {

      let email = firstContainerTextField.text ?? ""

      let newString = email.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: ",", options: .literal, range: nil)

      self.ref.child("users").child("allUsers").child(newString).setValue(true)

      self.ref.child("users").child((user?.uid)!).setValue(["Email": email])

      FIRAuth.auth()!.signIn(withEmail: email,
                             password: password)

    } else {
      //registration failure
    }
```

This is the code from the New User VC (partial).

So the node that says "users" and "allUsers" looks like this on Firebase Console

```
users
    allUsers
        bob@bob,com: true
        ted@ted,com: true
```

The 'true' part was just so I could get the bob@bob,com onto the database...the true part will never be used for anything.

On the log in VC I honestly cannot figure out what to do

A previous answer said to use

```
hasChildren()
```

And I used that and then googled what to do with that 
and I tried using something like this

```
ref.child("users").child("allUsers").queryEqual(toValue: newString)
  .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

if snapshot.hasChildren() {

    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {
    ....


}



  });
```

But I just cannot seem to get anywhere with it.

How can I simply see if a textfield.text == an email already stored in firebase?

(I did convert the '.' to ',' when comparing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use email addresses as keys. Email addresses are dynamic and may change (as in if the users wants to change it) and if they do, you'll have a mess on your hands as every node that directly used that email would have be deleted and re-created.

Best practice is to disassociate key's from the data they contain.

Here's the structure to use

```
emails
  -Yiaisjpa90is
    email: "dude@test.com"
  -Yijs9a9js09a
    email: "thing@test.com"
```

then you simply query the email node for the email you are looking for, and handle accordingly if it exists.

And some code

```
emailsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "email").queryEqual(toValue: "dude@test.com")
         .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
     if snapshot.value is NSNull {
        print("the snapshot was null, no email found")
     } else {
        print("email was found, YIPEE")
     }  
})
```

For completeness it would be a little more Swifty to use

```
if snapshot.exists() {
  print("found it")
} else {
  print("no email found")
}
```

Comment: I have the code in as you wrote it and for once it is actually doing something, however It only prints "no email found" even tho I do have it in the database

Comment: @RubberDucky4444 Well, if your Firebase Structure is identical to the one I posted, and the code is the same it must work as I copied and pasted it from my project. Make sure your emailsRef = rootRef.child("emails") as well.

Comment: the only thing I changed is 'toValue: "dude@test.com")' to 'toValue: email)' because email is what I am trying to compare against

Comment: I had a lowercase vs uppercase issue, Thanks!

Comment: Does Firebase compare case sensitive between whats entered in the text fields on a form vs whats stored in the json pair on the back end?!

Comment: @FamicTech Everything in Firebase is case sensitive. We store anything that's going to be searched as lower case along with the 'displayed' version. i.e. in our users node we have  uid_0/displayName = "Jay" along with uid_0/searchable = "jay"