# Filter in specific firebase structure

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I looking for method how to filtering my firebase. I know that is on stack overflow a lot of examples but my configuration is different - see below:

[image]

and my code to fetch data is:

```
let usersDatabaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("usersDatabase").child(userID).child("Customers")
    usersDatabaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let childSnap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let userCustomerSnap = childSnap

            for customer in userCustomerSnap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                let customerSnap = customer
                let dict = customerSnap.value as! [String: Any]

                let employee = dict["Assigned employee"]
```

then I appending employee to my Model.
Is possible to filter my cells in tableView by employee? (when I tap on button with name of employee tableView should showing only its services)

Comment: You're going to run into a LOT of problems with this structure and it's unclear what 'filter' means in this use case. Are you asking if you can query for a node that contains a single employee? Or something else? As it is, you're getting all the child nodes within Customer so you could put each child node's data in an object, store those objects in an array and 'filter' them. But is that what you're asking how to do?

Comment: There is some debate about using email addresses as keys but for me, I discourage it. See [emails as keys are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386373/compare-textfield-text-to-firebase-string-swift/41387240#41387240). Also, if Alice Glockam gets married and changes her name to Alice Smith; what are you going to do? Well, you'll have to find, delete and re-create every node in your database referring to  Alice Glockam.

Comment: oh - and the data may be too deep so you may want to [denormalize](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) it. Lastly, PLEASE include structures as text, not images, in questions.

Answer (score 0):

Structure your database in this manner. Let me know if you need more assisstance here.

[image]